# Struggling to write regex to match operands separately

Tags: regex

I have some sample text

```
project=blah AND blah=something OR issuetype!="blah" AND someissue IN somefunction("blah") OR blahing <= "somehing"
```

I'm trying to write a regular expression which can match the operands and the AND/OR separately.

So for example:

- match 1 group 1 will be project
- match 1 group 2 will be blah
- match 2 group 1 will be AND
- match 3 group 1 will be blah
- match 3 group 2 will be something

etc..

I'm getting close with this expression

```
(((?!AND |OR |or |and ).*?)(>=|<=|~|!=|=|!~|>|<| IS | IS NOT | WAS | WAS IN | WAS NOT | WAS NOT IN | CHANGED IN | NOT IN| IN )(?!AND |OR |or |and ).*?)\s|(AND |and |OR |or )
```

but it's just not matching the last 2 operands.

Comment: Perhaps `(?:(AND|OR)\s+)?(\S+?)\s*([<>!]?=|!?~|[<>]|IN)\s*(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/haLe5m/1

Comment: Really close, but it's matching "AND <next operation>"  like   "AND blah=something"

Comment: So do you mean it should not match that by itself? So do not match `AND blah=something` but do match `project=blah AND blah=something` ?

Comment: No, what I mean is there should be 3 separate matches; project=blah, AND, blah=something

Comment: The proper solution is to use a parser. Regex can be useful for simple tokenization but as soon as you want support e.g. for arbitrarily nested parentheses you will need a real parser anyway.

Comment: Whenever you  give an example (e.g., `"project=blah AND blah=something..."`) you should always give the desired return value, even if you may think it's obvious. I, for one, do not understand what that return value would be here. Would it be an array of matches of a regular expression? If so, let's see it.

Comment: You need to help me here... from my perspective I gave the literal values I was expecting. I gave an example of the first 3 matches in the question, and anytime I've mentioned expected values, I've used the literal values in the example string.  Or do you mean my example string should be something more real world?

Answer (score -2):

Warning first: this is a not a catch all solution.

If everysthing is in the format mentioned in your question something like this:

```
(?:(AND|OR)\s+|^\s*)("[^"]*"|[^\s\(=<>!]+(?:\((?:\s*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\)]*)\s*,?)*\))?)(?:\s*)(!?=|[<>]=?|IN)\s*("[^"]*"|[^\s\(=<>!]+(?:\((?:\s*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\)]*)\s*,?)*\))?)(?:\s*)
```

if you also want to accept things like

```
A = B OR FALSE OR test=123
```

then it could be extended to:

```
(?:(AND|OR)\s+|^\s*)("[^"]*"|[^\s\(=<>!]+(?:\((?:\s*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\)]*)\s*,?)*\))?)(?:\s*)(?:(!?=|[<>]=?|IN)\s*("[^"]*"|[^\s\(=<>!]+(?:\((?:\s*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\)]*)\s*,?)*\))?))?(?:\s*)
```

match structure:
Match Group 1: joining term to previous (AND/OR)
Match Group 2: left site of the comparison
Match Group 3: comparison term (=, !=, >, <, >=, <=)
Match Group 4: Right site of the comparison

Match group 1: `(?:(AND|OR)\s+|^\s*)` - (`AND` or `OR`) or beginning of the line

Match Group 2: `("[^"]*"|[^\s\(=<>!]+(?:\((?:\s*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\)]*)\s*,?)*\))?)`

- "[^"]*" - anything that starts with a double quote and ends with it as well.
- `[^\s\(=<>!]+(?:\((?:\s*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\)]*)\s*,?)*\))?`

  - `[^\s\(=<>!]+` anything non space and not `(`or a comparison operator
  - (?:((?:\s*(?:"[^"]*"|[^)]*)\s*,?)*))? `- optionally followed by a`(something, "something else",...)`

    - closing brackets in quotation marks are accounted for

Match Group 3: `(!?=|[<>]=?|IN)` - the comparison operators

Match Group 4: same as match group 2

It will also accept spaces in with in `""` where needed. Limitations I see: it will break if you try something like

```
A = somefunc1(somefunc2())
```

Also multiline inputs might break it as well.

It should basically have the whole  line matched. Meaning that if there is a space between match x and match x+1 then you encountered either something not supported by this regex or the input is wrong